# Application crashes when Receiving SMS using Broadcast Receiver Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm making an app that can read incoming sms and then retrieve text sms to write it on edittext in my activity. My app is like Whatsapp when verifying code using sms. The application runs normally when the activity that holds the verification text code is still running, but when the activity is not running (activity finished), the application crashes when incoming sms.
Please help me, I have been having this problem for a long time and it has not been resolved. Thank you very much for the help.
I get error message like this,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.rental.roby.okkarent.aplikasi.helper.SmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2590)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.rental.roby.okkarent.aplikasi.helper.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:40)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2571)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is my broadcast receiver code,

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static SmsListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            //You must check here if the sender is your provider and not another one with same text.

            String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            String verificationCode = getVerificationCode(messageBody);

            //Pass on the text to our listener.
            Log.d("","--------------------------------------------------------"+context);
            if(verificationCode != null){
                   // Toast.makeText(context, verificationCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mListener.messageReceived(verificationCode);
            }
        }

    }


    public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    private String getVerificationCode(String message) {
        String code = null;
        int index = message.indexOf(":");


        if (index != -1) {
            int start = index + 2;
            int length = 4;
            code = message.substring(start, start + length);
            return code;
        }

        return code;
    }
}
```

And this is the interface,

```
public interface SmsListener {

        public void messageReceived(String messageText);

}
```

And finally in my activity, I add code like this to write code verification automatically,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fom_verifikasi);


        // asking for sms code verification, 
        get_verification_code(no_hp);  

        // catch incoming sms
        SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
                //Log.d("Text",messageText);
                // write verficaation code to edittext
                kode.setText(messageText);
            }
        });



    }
```

This is in manifest,

```
<receiver android:name="com.rental.roby.okkarent.aplikasi.helper.SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes the bundle for SMS is null so check before process it, like this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                // 
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you thank you very much, you realy saved my day :) :)
Thank you @Muthkrishnan Rajendran